# Set Header Height with Safe Area Insets with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I can pass `screenOptions` to the Navigator with
a `headerStyle` object with a `height` property, but I'd like the height to take into account the `SafeAreaInsets` and not be a fixed value

There's `getDefaultHeaderHeight` function that takes into account the `statusBarHeight` here https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/dbe961ba5bb243e8da4d889c3c7dd6ed1de287c4/packages/drawer/src/views/Header.tsx#L8 - is there a way I can call this function and simply add `n` pixels across all devices?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about in React Navigation 5, but `height` is not a supported property of `headerStyle` in [React Navigation 6](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerstyle). The rest of this response is based on references to and my personal experience with React Navigation 6.

You may need to write a fully [custom header component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#header) to achieve what you want. React Navigation even has a Guide on [supporting safe areas](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/#use-the-hook-for-more-control). Summarizing the Guide from React Navigation, plus a little extra real-world usage of it, you can then use the `useSafeAreaInsets` hook from `react-native-safe-area-context` and then in the style for the `View` surrounding your custom header, you can use the `top` value from the hook response as `paddingTop` to ensure that your header avoids the status bar area. If the rest of the height of your header needs to be explicitly defined, you'll need to add that `top` value to your height number as the `height` property of this `View`. If the height of your header is dynamic and based on its content, you probably don't actually need to set an explicit height on your header.

Example:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      // only us height if you REALLY need it, height should be dynamic based on content
      header: () => <View style={{ paddingTop: insets.Top, height: value + insets.Top }}>
        {content of your custom header}
      </View>
    });
  }, [insets, navigation]);
};
```